# Derivation of Newton-Raphson Method for Maximum Likelihood Estimation of GLM Parameter

Tags: generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, irls

I am currently self-studying Generalized Linear Models after learning about linear regression in my undergraduate study. My undergraduate program is not statistics so I have some difficulties in understanding some concepts here.

## Current Understanding:

Given a Newton-Raphson update equation:

$\beta_{new} = \beta_{old} - \frac{f'(\beta_{old})}{f''(\beta_{old})}$

Consider independently and identically distributed random variables $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n$ that follows a distribution of the exponential family. To obtain the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\beta}$ for the parameter $\beta_j$, define a score equation $U = \frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \beta_j}$, where $\ell(\beta)$ is the log-likelihood function defined as:

$\frac{y\theta - b(\theta)}{a(\phi)}+c(y,\phi)$

To maximize the log-likelihood function with respect to $\beta$, take the first derivative of the score function and equate it to $0$ for each $j$. However, because the relationship between $\beta$ and $\ell$ is mediated through $\theta$, instead of differentiate it directly, chain rule is employed:

$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \beta_j} = \frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta} \cdot \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \mu}\cdot \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \eta}\cdot \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial \beta_j}$

Each component is derived as:

- $\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta} = \frac{y-b'(\theta)}{a(\phi)} = \frac{(y-\mu)}{a(\phi)}$
- $\mu = \mathbb{E}(y) = b'(\theta)\Rightarrow \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \theta} = b''(\theta)$
- $\eta = \sum\beta_j x_{ij}\Rightarrow \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial \beta_j} = x_{ij}$
- $g'(\mu)\cdot \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \eta} = 1\Rightarrow \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \eta} = \frac{1}{g'(\mu)}$

which gives:
$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \beta_j} = \frac{y-\mu}{a(\phi)b''(\theta)} \cdot \frac{1}{g'(\mu)}\cdot x_{ij}$

The second derivative of the function is given as:

$\frac{\partial^2 \ell}{\partial\beta_j\beta_k} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_k}\left[\frac{y-\mu}{a(\phi)b''(\theta)}\cdot \frac{1}{g'(\mu)}\cdot x_{ij}\right]
    = -\frac{\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \beta_k}}{a(\phi)b''(\theta)}\cdot \frac{1}{g'(\mu)}\cdot x_{ij}$

The $\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \beta_k}$ is also computed with chain rule:

$\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \beta_k} = \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \theta}\cdot \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \eta} \cdot \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial \beta_k}
    = \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \theta}\cdot \left[\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \mu}\cdot \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \eta}\right] \cdot \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial \beta_k}
    = b''(\theta)\cdot \left[\frac{1}{b''(\theta)}\cdot \frac{1}{g'(\mu)}\right]\cdot x_{ik}
    = \frac{1}{g'(\mu)}x_{ik}$

Which gives the second derivative:

$\frac{\partial^2 \ell}{\partial \beta_j\beta_k} = \frac{1}{a(\phi)b''(\theta)}\cdot -\frac{1}{g'(\mu)}x_{ik}\cdot \frac{1}{g'(\mu)}\cdot x_{ij}
    = -\frac{1}{a(\phi)b''(\theta)[g'(\mu)]^2}x_{ij}x_{ik}
    = -\frac{1}{Var(Y)[g'(\mu)]^2}x_{ij}x_{ik}$

## Confusion:

<s>1. I read up about the topic on a few textbooks (McCallagh & Nelder, Dobson & Barnett, Hardin & Hilbe, etc) and I encounter several different names of the update equation. I have encountered Newton-Raphson, iterative weighted least squares and iterative re-weighted least squares. I got confuse which is which. If I were to take a guess:
- Up until the derivation of the first and second derivative would be Newton-Raphson;
- When weights $w_i$ are introduced, the method is called iterative weighted least squares;
- When the expectation of second derivative (instead of the second derivative itself) is used, it is called the iterative re-weighted least squares.</s>

Is my understanding correct?

2. After obtaining the first and second derivative, there seems to be an introduction of the term $w_i = \frac{1}{a(\phi)b''(\theta)[g'(\mu)]^2}$ and $z_i$ into the equation and represent the equation in vector form. I am particularly confused with the definition of $z_i$ as the authors seems to define $z_i$ as different thing.

   - Dobson & Barnett define $z_i$ as $\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ik}\beta_{old}+(y_i-\mu_i)g'(\mu)$ (eq. 4.24, p. 73);
   - McCullagh & Nelder define $z_i$ as $\hat{\beta_0}+(y-\hat{\mu}_0)g'(\mu_0)$ (p. 40);
   - Hardin & Hilbe define $z_i$ as $(y-\mu)g'(\mu) + (\eta^{r-1}-\text{offset})$ (eq. 3.47, p.37)

   From the first derivative I managed to derive, I initially thought $z_i$ would be $(y_i-\mu_i)\cdot g'(\mu_i)$. So which is true?
   I suppose it has something to do with Taylor expansion of the log-likelihood function $\ell$, which is given as $\ell(\beta_{new}) = \ell(\beta_{old}) + \ell'(\beta_{old})(\beta_{new} - \beta_{old})$, but I could not understand where the $z_i$ come from. It does resembles the first derivative in some sort, but the first derivative is a product, and $z_i$ is a summation.
3. I came across an equation $X^TWX\beta^{(m)} = X^TWz$ from Dobson & Barnett (eq. 4.25, p.73). How does it derived from the Newton-Raphson procedure to come up with such equation? This makes me even more confused with the whole thing.

These are the questions I encountered as of now. Appreciate if there's anyone who can help clear my doubts. I am not from a statistics background so there might be some concepts that might be fundamental but I got it wrong. Thank you for your help!

The books I've used:

1. An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models, 4th Edition (2018) by Annette Dobson & Adrian Barnett
2. Generalized Linear Models, 2nd Edition (1989) by James McCullagh & John Nelder
3. Generalized Linear Models and Extensions, 4th Edition (2018) by James Hardin & Joseph Hilbe

---

**Edits:**

After some time I managed to understand the first question. I confused Newton-Raphson as a method of estimation at the beginning, and after reading up on Fisher Information, CRLB and deriving the equations, I managed to understand the difference between the three. With this I strike off the first question.

Comment: iterative weighted and iterative re-weighted are the same. One is just more pedantic.